# Lower mash temperature

Tags: mash

I missed my mash temperature by 4 degrees a few days ago.  I was shooting for 152 but got 149.5.  Then I checked my calibration today and my Thermometer was 1.2 high.  So I mashed at around 148.3.  Its an IPA, from what I see it will just dry it out a little.  Will it change my beers taste that much?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not much change at all.  Today's malts are so high in diastatic power that mash temps make a lot less difference than they used to.

Answer (score 1):

It should make your final beer noticeably dryer, indeed. It will also raise fermentability (more sugar will be converted to alcohol), so you will get higher ABV and you might get little less body (in the mouthfeel sense).

There is nothing to be worried about. You will get more west-coast result, which will most definitely be a good beer.

Please let us know how it turned out when it's done.